# How Spring transaction is mapped to underlying database connection

Tags: spring, transactions

I am trying to understand in background how transaction is mapped to jdbc connection i.e one jdbc connection can be parallely used for multiple spring transactions at the same time or one connection is totally reserved for one transaction at a given time and only released after transaction is complete.

Comment: A single `Connection` only supports a single concurrent transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I my opionion one of the best way to understanding how Spring managed transactions is reading [Transaction Management Reference Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).